# Symbol .gdb into ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I am new to ArcGIS.

I am doing a nautical chart and I have a *.gdb file in a USB with the symbology I want to use in my nautical chart.

I have looked everywhere but it seems the methods I have being following havent done what I expected.

What I want is to enter this *gdb file, which is made up of shape and point files, into ArcMap so that I can later select this symbols for specific points in the chart.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance
Hector

Comment: Are you asking about how to add data to ArcMap, or how to bring in the specific symbology? (Often symbology is stored in a `.lyr` file, not in a geodatabase...)

Comment: Hi Erica, I have a gdb file with loads of symbols to use. Is there a way to bring this into arcmap. Thanks

Comment: You may not be aware but there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcGIS for Desktop questions already answered.